# Create SharePoint Groups in SharePoint App . C# or JS?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I want to create sharepoint groups when i deploy my app . This will happen one time only . So i want when i deploy the app to check if the groups exist. If they don't to create them.

I found many articles suggesting to use javascript . Is there a way to create them when i first deploy the app ? How can i do that with javascript and with C# , since C# functions can only be used / triggered with event receivers . Is there another way ?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement SharePoint add-in event, so you could check the group exits or not, if not exists, create the group by CSOM(c#).

[image]

Guideline:

[Create an add-in event receiver in SharePoint Add-ins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/create-an-add-in-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-add-ins)

Answer (score 0):

We can use JSOM for creating custom SharePoint groups and assign permissions to groups in SharePoint 2013.

[Create SharePoint Security Group Using JSOM](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a30324/create-sharepoint-security-group-using-jsom/)

[Create User Group In SharePoint Host Web Using SharePoint Hosted App (JSOM)](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-user-group-in-sharepoint-host-web-using-sharepoint-hosted-app-jsom)

Off the top of my head, it's Site collection permissions that you need to create the group.

Comment: Thanks for the response by now i have another issue. When i deploy my app it won't take me to the app homepage. Instead it just shows me the code in visual studio. Its strange